# Check if numbers are of the same sign in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a program that prints the results of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of 2 inputs. In order to have the results of, say, 3/5 being printed as "0.60" and not ".60" I added a line to print a 0 before the output. But then, say, -3/5 will be printed as "0.-60" and not "-0.60". So I need a conditional statement to check if the numbers are of the same sign, and, if not, print "-0" and then the output multiplied by -1. But my statement,  `if [[ $($a > 0) -eq $($b > 0) ]]`, does not work, the terminal sends the "command not found" error. How do I fix it?
Full code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
b=$2
echo $(($a + $b))
echo $(($a - $b))
echo $(($a * $b))
if [[ $b -eq 0 ]] 
then
    echo "#"
else
    if [[ $a/$b -eq 0 ]]
    then
        if [[ $($a > 0) -eq $($b > 0) ]]
        then
            echo -n 0
            echo "scale=2; $a/$b " | bc -l
        else
            echo -n "-0"
            echo "scale=2; -1 * ($a/$b) " | bc -l
        fi
    else
        echo "scale=2; $a/$b " | bc -l
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `if [[ $a -gt 0 && $b -gt 0 ]]`; though you have other issues with your code ...

Comment: `$a/$b` does not perform a division but rather builds a string of 2 variables separated by a `/`, eg: `a=3; b=5; echo $a/$b` generates `3/5` (a string), and from there `[[ '3/5' -eq 0 ]]` is nonsensical (ie, numeric comparion between the string `3/5` and the number `0`)